# Can I change the css of a parent component from a child component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

app.component.html

```
<div class="container main-area">
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

global.css

```
.container{
max-width : 1022 px;
}
```

child.component.html

```
<div class="media-area">
<media-area></media-area>
</div>
```

Here my child component is also taking max-width of 1022px which is from the container of app.component.html

How can I override that and make

```
.media-area{
width: 100%; (it should take full screen width and not the parent container width)
}
```

apart from this component, all other component needs the container width to be 1022px

Comment: Take a look at https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context

Answer (score 3):

Try using **vw** css units for setting element's width. These are relative to 1% of the width of the viewport.

```
.media-area{
width: 100vw; /* = 100% width of viewport/the browser window size */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **vw** css syntax can be used. The child component will adjust according to container's width as you want. For 100% width coverage, use `width: 100vw`.